# How can I find a function that contains a set of given points?

Tags: python, function, math, regression, sympy

If I have set of points, how can I find the a function that fits it? I looked on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405609/is-it-possible-to-find-function-that-contains-every-given-point), and it worked great until I tried a more complicated function. I'm trying to find the sigmoid function when given a list of points from the function in python. I know that any polynomial can work, but I want to find the simplest function the will fit those points. By simplest, I mean the least amount of terms. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Function

x = Symbol("x")
xs = np.array([0, -1, 1, .5, -.5])
ys = np.array([.5, .269, .731, .622, .378])

fx = ys[0]

for i in range(len(xs)-1):
    #g(x) function
    gx = x-xs[0]
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        gx *= (x-xs[j])

    #lambda function. Make sure to watch out for the first loop when fx is not a symbol
    if type(fx) == np.float64:
        lmx = (ys[i+1]-fx)/(gx.subs(x, xs[i+1]))
    else:
        lmx = (ys[i+1]-fx.subs(x, xs[i+1]))/(gx.subs(x, xs[i+1]))

    #Redefine f(x)
    fx = fx +(lmx)*(gx)
fx = fx.simplify()
print(fx)
```

The output to this is `-1.48029736616688e-16*x**4 - 0.0173333333333334*x**3 + 1.48029736616688e-16*x**2 + 0.248333333333333*x + 0.5` but I was expecting 1/(1+e^(-x)).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you know that a polynomial of some order will always satisfy your requirement, right? You can fit any set of points with a polynomial function (Taylor series). In your case, that is what happened. I am not exactly sure then, what your question is about. If you're fitting a curve, you should know which function you want to fit. Fitting sets of points and asking, what functions go through those points is a bit pointless since there are infinitely many of them (usually).

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess what I'm asking is to find the simplest function. I'll edit the question.

Comment: That's just not possible.  There are an infinite number of functions, but automated curve fitters are looking for a polynomial fit.  If you know it's an inverse exponential, you can have it fit the coefficients, but it's can't try all of the different KINDS of functions.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Should I delete the post then?

Comment: That's not "simplest" in your sense, but they often use [splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) for this. And what you're trying to do is not possible at all, as long as you don't specify kinds of functions manually (like `a/(1 + b*e^(-x))`)

Comment: Would there be any way to find the function with the least amount of terms then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that any polynomial can work

Yes, you can use [`interpolate`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyfuncs.interpolate) or [`interpolating_poly`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.specialpolys.interpolating_poly) on your data points like this:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.polys.specialpolys import interpolating_poly
from sympy.polys.polyfuncs import interpolate

x = Symbol("x")
xs = [0, -1, 1, .5, -.5]
ys = [.5, .269, .731, .622, .378]

xs = [QQ.convert(i) for i in xs]
ys = [QQ.convert(i) for i in ys]

p1 = expand(interpolating_poly(len(xs),x,X=xs,Y=ys)).as_poly()
display(p1)

p2 = interpolate( [(xs[i],ys[i]) for i in range(len(xs))], x).as_poly()
display(p2)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

---

> I'm trying to find the sigmoid function when given a list of points from the function in python

Since there's multiple types of [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), I'll pick the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) because [heinwol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10240583) also mentioned it in the comments. It's possible to define the general form of the function in SymPy, use Scipy to do the curve fitting, then replace the coefficients found in the function, and then plot it to see if it matches the input data points.

```py
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = Symbol("x")
xs = [0, -1, 1, .5, -.5]
ys = [.5, .269, .731, .622, .378]

L,k,x0,x = symbols('L k x_0 x')
f = L/(1+(exp(-k*(x-x0))))
display(f)

syms = list(f.free_symbols)
syms.remove(x)
syms.insert(0,x)
py_f = lambdify(syms,f)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(py_f, xs, ys, maxfev = 4 * (10**5))

syms.pop(0)
subs_arg = dict(list(zip(syms, popt)))

f1 = f.subs(subs_arg)
display(f1)

f2 = lambdify([x],f1)

# plot input data points
plt.scatter(np.array(xs),np.array(ys),color="red")

# plot fitted function
xp = np.arange(min(xs), max(xs)+1, 0.05)
yp = f2(xp)
plt.plot(xp,yp,color="blue")
plt.show()
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

All the code in this post is also available [in this repo](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/tree/master/so-67250024).

---

> Would there be any way to find the function with the least amount of terms then?

This is open to interpretation and ambiguous. The multiple types of [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples) are not characterized just by a number of terms. It might be possible to write down a catalog of such functions, come up with your own metric to differentiate which one is more simple, then do the fitting for each of them and at the end decide which one was a better fit.